# How to declare an Optional type in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Java 8 has `Optional<T>` which is nice way to declare optional types as described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html). 
Is there an equivalent way to that in C# ?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx Nullable types.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: Nullable types work only for value types, as far as I know

Comment: For reference types you could possibly use code contracts as per this article http://blog.coverity.com/2013/11/20/c-non-nullable-reference-types/#.U53fXy29KSM

Comment: Since C# 8.0 there are [nullable reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references).

Answer (score 1):

As per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16199227/optional-return-in-c-net) You could make a struct that mimics this this type of functionality.