# Option type alternatives in c#

Tags: c#, functional-programming, option-type

I want to use an Option type in C#.
Are there any good alternatives for an Option type in C# like [`'T option` in F#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370544.aspx), [`Option[A]` in Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.7.4/scala/Option.html), or [`Optional<T>` in Java 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html)?

I know that F#'s `'T option` can be used in C# like an external library (`FSharp.Core`), but I think that is... Well, is it preferable to do so? There may be some problems like name conflicts.

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16199227/optional-return-in-c-net

Comment: I think the short answer is no. The long answer is in the duplicate.

Comment: Nothing exists like that currently.  There are some "workarounds" but they aren't satisfactory.  The best you can do is go over to the Roslyn github and open a feature request https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn Check the Wiki for discussions about future language features https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki This is where new features are being incubated/discussed/worked on.

Answer (score -4):

I think you are looking for [Nullable types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx), which are similar to Javas Optional.

Comment: No. Nullable types are more like primitive wrapper classes in Java. Not Optional type.

Comment: Additionaly, they do not work with reference types

Comment: Sorry, did not use Java for seven years...

Comment: Totally different concepts, Nullable is intended to make a struct accept null, Option is a design concept to avoid working with null.

Comment: I'm learning C# having experience with Java/Scala.  I found this to be the correct answer in a .NET Core 3.1 environment.