# Generic type parameters bound to value types - making them nullable

Tags: c#, generics, nullable, boxing, nullable-reference-types

I have a generic class to represent either a result or an error, but not both:

```
public class Result<TValue, TError>
    where TValue : notnull
    where TError : notnull
{
    private readonly bool succeeded;
    private readonly TValue? value;
    private readonly TError? error;

    public static Result<TValue, TError> Success(TValue value) =>
        new(true, value ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(value)), default);

    public static Result<TValue, TError> Failure(TError error) =>
        new(false, default, error ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(error)));

    protected Result(bool succeeded, TValue? value, TError? error)
    {
        this.succeeded = succeeded;
        this.value = value;
        this.error = error;
    }
    
    public bool Successful(
        [NotNullWhen(true)] out TValue? value,
        [NotNullWhen(false)] out TError? error)
    {
        if (succeeded)
        {
            value = this.value!;
            error = default;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            value = default;
            error = this.error!;
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

This works as I want for classes. For example, if TValue is `object` then the `value` field and `value` parameters are `object?`. However, I've realised that when a generic type parameter is a value type, decorating it with the `?` doesn't make it `Nullable`. This is presumably because doing so would change the underlying type rather than just commenting on its nullability. Is there any way to reference the `Nullable` version of a generic type?

Comment: I suppose you know that if you constrain `where TValue : struct` then `TValue?` will always mean `Nullable<TValue>`. But then you cannot use your type for situations where `TValue` is a reference type.

Comment: Thanks @JeppeStigNielsen. Yes, I had a go at creating the <class, class>, <class, struct>, <struct, class> and <struct, struct> combinations, but it'd be a shame because as well as the replication, each version would need a different name.

Comment: Maybe you must give up all the `null` stuff and write or find an [option type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Option_type) to use instead (like `Maybe<T>` or `Optional<T>` or something; where `T` is not constrained to value types), like in thread [Optional return in C#.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16199227/) or others. Of course, syntax like `??` and attributes like `[NotNullWhen(...)]` will not work with that.

Comment: Thanks @JeppeStigNielsen. It might be the way to go. I did like the [NotNullWhen], as the code analysis works well from the caller site, but that doesn't seem to work with Nullables anyway. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is language limitation.
See [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references#generics)

> If the type argument for T is a value type, T? references the same value type, T. For example, if T is an int, the T? is also an int.